# What is a "Stochastic theory"

Tags: stochastic-processes, soft-question

Im currently reading [The Generalized Composite Commodity Theorem and Food Demand Estimation](https://ageconsearch.umn.edu/record/20107/files/sp04re01.pdf).

In the paper the theorem is discribed as a "stochastic theory of aggregation over diverse consumer products".

What does "stochastic theory" mean in this context?

Comment: stochastic means random

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I know that. What is a stochastic theory though?

Comment: the prices and price change of consumer products?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown is there a source i should see? Can you direct me to something? This is the first time im seeing the term. (I know what the word stochastic means)

Comment: @EconJohn Google “stochastic theory” and go from there

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown i have done that and have found nothing